# How to run arbitrary string as command

Tags: python, getattr

I see answers where getattr() is utilized for some simple one method/function call.

How about arbitrary string, e.g. doing web parsing here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

f = urllib.urlopen(link) # link comes from database, e.g. 'http://www.example.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

text = soup.find(True, 'text').get_text() # Now this is hardcoded
```

Works fine, but how about running parser string which comes from database? String can be like:

```
soup.find("div", "layout left").find(id=True).get_text()
```

or pretty match anything, depends on webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate an arbitrary Python expression stored in a string.  However, this is dangerous.  A hacker or an unscrupulous user could insert malicious code into the database (e.g., `1000000**1000000` to cause Python to go nuts).

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution here! Have to think consequences more related to security as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Why can not you advance from the string line to construct a list and do something like this?

```py
tags = soup.findAll(['div','span'])
```

or

```
soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name in ['div', 'span'] or tag['id'] == "eggs")
```

or maybe even better:

```
tags = soup.findAll(['div', 'span'])
tags.extend(soup.findAll(id="eggs"))
```

If you want to exclude some tags by condition you can add the condition to lambda expression.

**Example:**

From DB:

```py
s = 'div;span;table' # or something like this with structure
```

Do like this:

```
tags_list = s.split(';')
tags = soup.findAll(tags_list)
```

I think you got the main idea.

Comment: I'm not sure did I understood correctly.. but I'm trying to make system where one can easily (not coding per se) add new sites and tailored string for parsing, all this just inserting data via fancy UI to DB.